# Create Azure Container Instance from an Javascript-based Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure

I'd like to create an Azure Container Instance from a Javascript-based Azure Function. Unfortunately, I receive an error message:

> Result: Failure Exception: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property 'properties' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.containers[0]', line 1, position 79.'. Stack: RestError: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property 'properties' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.containers[0]', line 1, position 79.'. at handleErrorResponse (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/@azure/core-client/dist/index.js:1321:19) at deserializeResponseBody (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/@azure/core-client/dist/index.js:1256:45) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

This is how I want to create the instance using the Azure SDK with @azure/arm-containerinstance package:

```
async function CreateDockerContainer(var1, var2) {
    const subscriptionId = process.env['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'].toString();
    const resourceGroupName = process.env['RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME'].toString();
    const containerInstanceName = 'ContainerAFTest';
    const containerImageName = 'xxx.azurecr.io/blender-container:1.0.0';
    // const containerName = 'blender-container';
    const containerGroupName = 'blender-container-group';
    // const containerGroup = new ContainerGroup();

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const client = new ContainerInstanceManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);
const containerGroup = {
    location: 'westeurope',
    containers: [
        {
            name: containerInstanceName,
            properties: {
                image: containerImageName,
                resources: {
                    requests: {
                        cpu: 1.0,
                        memoryInGB: 3.0
                    }
                },
                environmentVariables: [
                    {
                        name: 'var1',
                        value: var1
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'var2',
                        value: var2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    osType: 'Linux',
    restartPolicy: 'Never'
};

const containerInstance = await client.containerGroups.beginCreateOrUpdate(
    resourceGroupName,
    containerGroupName,
    containerGroup
);

console.log('Created container group: ', containerInstance);
const containerResult = containerInstance;
return containerResult;
```

}

Do I miss something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The properties was set and that's wrong. Correct is:

```
const containerGroup = {
    location: 'westeurope',
    containers: [
        {
            name: containerInstanceName,

            image: containerImageName,
            resources: {
                requests: {
                    cpu: 1.0,
                    memoryInGB: 3.0
                }
            },
            environmentVariables: [
                {
                    name: 'var1',
                    value: var1
                },
                {
                    name: 'var2',
                    value: var2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    osType: 'Linux',
    restartPolicy: 'Never',
    imageRegistryCredentials: [
        {
            server: 'xxx',
            username: xxx,
            password: xxx
        }
    ]
};
```